# Compare double till precision 2

Tags: .net

I want to compare two double values till the second digit from decimal point. I am using following statement but I think it is not working properly.

```
dbl1.ToString("g2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Equals( dbl2.ToString("g2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
```

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: What's wrong with `dbl1.ToString("g2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == dbl2.ToString("g2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dbl1.ToString("g2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Equals( dbl2.ToString("g2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
```

is working for me.  I was just looking for any other alternative.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `Math.Abs(dbl1 - dbl2) < 0.01`. This will only consider the first two digits after the decimal point.

Comment: Doesn't work, rounding screws that up.  Example: 1.0049 vs 1.0099

Comment: @Hans: what do you mean? `Math.Abs(1.0049 - 1.0099) < 0.01` returns true for me (in C# using .net 4.0).

Comment: 1.0049 prints as "1.00", 1.0099 prints as "1.01", not equal.

Comment: @Hans: I'm sorry, but I don't see your point. As far as I understand the OPs question, he wants to compare two doubles up until the second digit after the decimal point, and as far as I can tell, this method works fine. What does printing have to do with it?